# why axios get method request send twice?

Tags: vue.js

[image]I run the axios get method to call php script.but request send twice
 how to solve this problem.
myfunction:-

```
   axios.get('http://13.233.179.174/customers_log.php',{
                  headers: {
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
                  },
                })
                  .then(function (response) {
                    $("#spinner").hide();
                    console.log('this is response work');
                    console.log(response.data);
                  })
                  .catch(function (error) {
                    $("#spinner").hide();
                    console.log(error);
                  })
```

Comment: Are you calling your function twice?

Comment: No but on console it show twice i am adding the picture please check.

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a **response** header. It does not go in your request

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Access-Control-Allow-Origin header work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work)

Comment: If the first request method is not Options, but Get also, check your event handler. Probably, you have to add something like @click.once

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It'a **Preflight request**

> It is an OPTIONS request, using three HTTP request headers: Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, and the Origin header.

Check here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request

Comment: where need to change on my function or backend?

Comment: No, you don't need to do anything. It works that way.

Comment: Thanks for helping.